# Google Cloud Function deployed from source failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my GCP function from a source zip that I upload and I'm having problems.

From the error logs, it looks like it downloads the source correctly, and inspecting the source package, it looks fine, but it fails some intermediate step about
`/tmp/source-archive.zip`

Any help would always be appreciated.

```
46317239ZCopying gs://gcf-sources-159756393638-us-central1/fetch-shader-f7a3587c-340b-45ce-84ea-59030f1df7cf/version-37/function-source.zip#1659135889258775...
- / [0 files][ 0.0 B/124.7 KiB] / [1 files][124.7 KiB/124.7 KiB]
- Operation completed over 1 objects/124.7 KiB.
- Archive: /tmp/source-archive.zip
-  End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not
-  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the
-  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
-  the last disk(s) of this archive.
- unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/source-archive.zip or
-  /tmp/source-archive.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/source-archive.zip.ZIP, period.
- ERROR
- ERROR: error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 9
```

Cheers all

Comment: Verify that your zip file is good. Are you using Windows (to generate the zip)? If you've access to the source, it may be easier to deploy from source ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source))

Comment: It should be a zip file, well built.